# Save XML file in C# without use XCData

Tags: c#, xml, xcdatamodel

I have a string like this on C#:

```
string sxml="<id>xpto</id>"
```

and I want to save an xml file using XLinq:

```
XElement cursosXML = new XElement("MenuItem", new XCData(sxml));
cursosXML.save("C:\\xpto.xml")
```

when I read my xml file this appears:

```
<MenuItem><![CDATA[<id>xpto</id>]]></MenuItem>
```

but I do not want `<![CDATA[`

How can I get this result?

```
<MenuItem>&lt;xpto&gt;3&lt;</MenuItem>
```

Comment: I don't always comment on grammar, but when I do, I'm actually having a hard time reading your paragraph

Comment: How about you express your problem a little bit more graphically  For example:  "I want this output `insert desired output here`, but I get this output: `insert actual output here`.  here's the code I'm generating output with: `insert code here`

Comment: sorry i don't know whats happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you should add the string to your element

```
        XElement sxml = XElement.Parse("<id>xpto</id>");
        XElement cursosXML = new XElement("MenuItem", sxml);
        cursosXML.Save("C:\\xpto.xml");
```

**Below Is an explanation of the troubles you've been having.  It's just here for your reference**

`<id>xpto</id>` is an XML Element, but you're adding it to your current element as though it were a literal string.  When you do this, the computer doesn't think you're adding a new child element to your main element, so it escapes it(explained later)

The code I posted calls `XElement.Parse(string)`, which will take your seralized xml string, and try to generate a valid `XElement` from it.

What's happening is that `&lt;` is an **escape sequence** for `<` and `&gt;` is an escape sequence for `>`.

the reason why your XML parser escapes `<` and `>` is because those characters have special meaning, and including them in your XML change the nature of XML.

It's kinda similar to how `\n` is an escape sequence for the newline character, and how `\\` is an escape sequence for `\`

Comment: thanks! i will search more, because i can't use xdata but i need save xml. thaks again

Comment: @user1774725  I've edited my answer, It should have your solution for you